# Deployment and updating VS2010 application

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that has a 'main' exe which is just a form with a number of icons. When a user starts the app the main form displays and the user then clicks an icon which launches the chosen app, which is a separate exe in the same directory.
At present the deployment is based on the 'main' project and the other (13) exes are added as files. All exes, including the main are indiviual VB projects and have their own version numbers as they are updated/debugged etc individually. Updates are dealt with using an Inno setup which the user simply installs into the 'main' directory, overwriting the existing files. This is under VB5. The code is now ported to VS2010 and I am looking for advice on a .NET deployment philosophy.

Can I repeat the (VB5) method in .NET (setup 'Main' and add other exes as files etc then overwrite updates)?

Is there a more efficient method under .NET?

Also, I would appreciate any advice on the easiest/best installer to use of; VS2010, Wix, Advancedinstaller (free version), any others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Have a look at ClickOnce for deployment philosophy.
  [msdn Deploying Windows Forms Applications with ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953320.aspx)
  if you don't like "ClickOnce" you can have a look at the "Setup project" of the Visual studio it isn't that bad.
- Yes you can repeat the setup 'Main' and add other exes as files

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at the WiX Installer: http://wix.codeplex.com/
The documentation is poor, but you can build very powerful installers. Especially you could build one installer, which fetches the necessary data from all projects and then builds one "big" installer.

Vb2010 can handle lots of projects in the same solution - maybe that could help to reduce redundancy.
But if you are staying with essentially unrelated projects I think your way is pretty ok.

Clickonce does not work under Windows XP, am I correct?